# How to return the length of a list as type Integer instead of Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to return the length of a list as an `Integer` type, but applying `length xs` returns the length as an `Int` type. How can I work around this issue?

This is what I am trying to achieve: (it does not work)

```
sizeList :: [Integer] -> Integer
sizeList xs = length xs
```

It works as soon as I change the return to `sizeList :: [Integer] -> Int` but I don't want to do so.

Comment: go with `genericLength` as Sebastian said - or reimplement length as an excercise :D

Comment: I hope you have well though about whether this is a good idea? Usually, it's not _possible_ to have a list so long you can't count it's length in `Int` – the reason being, the computer's memory is basically indexed with ints, so an architecture with sufficient memory will generally have big enough ints to measure any list. On a 64-bit platform, counting till overflow [takes ages](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^64+%2F+3GHz) anyway, even if you use an infinite list.   That's why the standard `length` function, IMO rightly, returns `Int` not `Integer`.

Comment: And on a 32-bit plattform, it will take 1.4 seconds, but at that point you would use (2^32 * 8 byte ~ 34GB).

Comment: I know. I tried emailing my instructor and pointing that out to him, but he was scrupulous! That's how he wanted it and that's how it was going to be. Period

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can either call [`genericLength`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericLength) from `Data.List`, or call [`length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) and use [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert the result.

Comment: Note that `genericLength` avoids a possible numeric overflow &mdash; although if your list is _that_ big, you're probably doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

There is also one trick I've seen in `Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!` that could be applied:

```hs
sum [1 | _ <- list]
```

Could be useful in some cases, perhaps.